# Twilio Invalid Access Token - Swift

Tags: swift, twilio, twilio-video

I am attempting to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lrdYBLEk60 and am getting Invalid Access Token - Code: 20101 returned when I follow everything to a tee. I changed nothing in the VideoQuickStart provided, other than adding my Twilio function link with identity: `https://carnelian-chinook-9032.twil.io/video-token?identity=doug`

**Code for function (same as video linked):**

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const AccessToken = Twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
    const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;

    const token = new AccessToken(context.ACCOUNT_SID, context.API_KEY, context.API_SECRET);
    token.identity = event.identity;

    const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({
        room: 'TestingRoom'
    });

    token.addGrant(videoGrant);

    callback(null, { token: token.toJwt() });
};
```

**Beginning of ViewController.swift from VideoQuickStart example**

```
import UIKit

import TwilioVideo

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: View Controller Members

    // Configure access token manually for testing, if desired! Create one manually in the console
    // at https://www.twilio.com/console/video/runtime/testing-tools
    var accessToken = "TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN"

    // Configure remote URL to fetch token from
    var tokenUrl = "https://carnelian-chinook-9032.twil.io/video-token?identity=doug"

    // Video SDK components
    var room: TVIRoom?
    var camera: TVICameraSource?
    var localVideoTrack: TVILocalVideoTrack?
    var localAudioTrack: TVILocalAudioTrack?
    var remoteParticipant: TVIRemoteParticipant?
    var remoteView: TVIVideoView?

    // MARK: UI Element Outlets and handles

    // `TVIVideoView` created from a storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: TVIVideoView!

    @IBOutlet weak var connectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var disconnectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var roomTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var roomLine: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var roomLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var micButton: UIButton!

    // MARK: UIViewController
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "QuickStart"
....
```

Anyone know what I can try for this? Or if they can follow the tutorial and it works on their end? Maybe the tutorial is a bit outdated? Maybe I need to enable something on my account? Anything helps, thanks!

Repo used for example: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue here is that you are using Test Credentials to create your token. [Twilio test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials) are only useful for testing API responses to requests to send a message, buy a number or make a phone call without actually triggering the action.

Switch out for your real credentials and everything should work just fine.

**Edit**

Using the quickstart that you linked to, [the access token is requested by this code](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/blob/20343950c2599d9530a34e55202676f3dfecf34b/Utils/Utils.swift#L21-L33) which doesn't parse the JSON and look for the token.

If you return just the token as a string payload instead of a JSON payload, then this should work. To update the function, change the `callback` to:

```
callback(null, token.toJwt());
```

Comment: Okay that's kinda what I was thinking, but as the tutorial shows under Functions > Config, you check the box for `Enable ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN` so that they can be grabbed from context. How do I have that grab the real credentials?

Comment: Have you overridden the ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN in the config section of Functions?

Comment: No, should I pass the real credentials explicitly in Config > Env Variables?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to pass them in the env variables. That's why I wondered if you had overridden them in there. I can't see another reason that your account sid would be set to your test credentials. I'm checking with the team to see what has happened here.

Comment: Can you double check whether you have set `ACCOUNT_SID` in Config > Env Variables and delete it if you have, please?

Comment: Yes, so I have passed only the API_KEY and API_SECRET in the environment variables, which I got from Programmable Video > Tools > API Keys . Standard key type, API_KEY = SID, API_SECRET = secret . I also have `Enable ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN` checked.

Comment: I also created a new trial account to make sure it wasn't my previous account, still have same issues after following the tutorial exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199984/discussion-between-dangerdoug-and-philnash).